# Schlüssel für die oder zur Tür

Tags: word-choice

Schlüssel für die oder zur Tür?

Ich habe beide Varianten gesehen.

Bedeuten sie das Gleiche?

Comment: /OT You probably didn't notice that you are (probably inadvertently) create a new account if you choose the _sign up_ instead of _login_. See [1](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/32839/barkas) [2](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/32838/barkas) [3](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/32828/barkas) [4](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/32825/barkas). You probably also want to ask for moderator attention to merge all these accounts into a single one

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: mods can't merge accounts. We need to contact the team for this: https://german.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts

Comment: @Takkat Thanks for giving the insight. I thought it was worth mentioning to contact you though then.

Answer (score 5):

Für gewöhnlich ist der Ausdruck

> der Schlüssel zur Tür

eine Kurzform für den Ausdruck

> der zur Tür gehörende Schlüssel,

und dann bedeutet er das gleiche wie

> der Schlüssel für die Tür.

Ich schrieb deshalb "für gewöhnlich", weil analog zu dem Beispielausdruck

> der Schlüssel zur Wohnung (die sich hinter einer Tür verbirgt)

auch

> der Schlüssel zur Tür (die sich hinter einer anderen Tür verbirgt)

denkbar wäre. Und dann wäre der Schlüssel **nicht** *für* die in Rede stehende Tür, sondern für die andere Tür, hinter der sich die in Rede stehende Tür verbirgt.

Comment: Ich denke, dass bei Deinem ersten Beispiel die 'Tür' in irgendeiner Weise ergänzt sein muss: _Ist das der Schlüssel zur Gartentür? Der Schlüssel zu Tür 7 ist weg. Schau mal, der Schlüssel hier passt nicht zu dieser Tür, siehst du?_ Bei 'der Schlüssel für die Tür' ist es ähnlich: Man könnte es so verwenden: 'Ist das der richtige Schlüssel für die Tür?', dann wäre das 'die' vor 'Tür' ein unbetontes Demonstrativpronomen, oder zurückverweisend (die Tür, über die wir gesprochen haben). Normalerweise verstehe 'der Schlüssel zur Tür' ohne Ergänzung wie in Deinem letzten Beispiel.

Comment: Sonderfall: "Schlüssel zum Glück" ist ein Idiom (und bedeutet u.a. "Flaschenöffner"), "Schlüssel für das Glück" oder gar "Schlüssel für die Tür zum Glück" würde man nicht sagen.